# Bluetooth Gone Haywire - Anyone know how to fix it?

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, error, headphones

[image: Bluetooth error]

Sorry for the image quality of the above pic, but as you can tell from the title of this article, I’m having some bluetooth (BT) issues, and as such, my BT keyboard wasn’t working, so I couldn’t take a proper screen shot.

Here’s the setup:

- mid 2007 Mac mini, 2.0GHz Intel Core Duo
- Mac OS X 10.7.5 (can’t install 10.9 – incompatible)
  (Installed a few months ago) Crucial RAM: 2GB kit (1GBx2) DDR2 PC2-5300 Unbuffered NON-ECC 1.8V 128Meg x 64 : CT2883304
- Apple BT Keyboard
- Kinivo BTH220 Bluetooth Stereo Headphones
- Installed a 500G hard disk a few years back
- Other peripherals attached:

  - eyeTV Hybrid
  - Logitech mxAir Mouse

Last night, my 2 bluetooth peripherals (keyboard & headphones) started going crazy and I’ve yet to figure out the cause or solution.  One thing I did last night (10/1/2014 at 7:30pm according to my log) before this all started happening was I performed a system update using “Software Update”.  It installed the Security Update 2014-004 and iTunes 11.4.  It could be a coincidence, but that’s awfully coincidental.

It also follows a recent iCloud issue from the night before.  The previous time I used the computer, I was having trouble using bonjour for screen-sharing with my first-gen iPad running VNC, so I had connected to another computer on the network to use Back-to-my-Mac.  But then I realized it wouldn’t work because I’d recently changed my Apple ID password.  I couldn’t figure out how to re-enter the password in 10.7, so in iCloud System Prefs, I logged out of iCloud & back in (both of those processes took forever and I just turned off the screen and let it run all night).

So then last night I was checking in on the iCloud status and got asked for my password.  So I turned on the first of my BT devices (Apple Keyboard) and tried to enter the system password.  But it kept saying I was entering the wrong password! Eventually, I opened up a Stickies Note and tried typing there and everything was coming out all-caps.  The caps-lock key wasn’t lit and turning it on/off didn’t change the capitalization.  I opened Apple’s virtual keyboard and it showed that I was holding both the caps-lock and shift key down.  I managed after a few tries to get them off, but then when I tried to enter the password again, it still wouldn’t work.  So I looked at the virtual keyboard again and it showed that the option key appeared to be depressed.  I turned that off using the virtual keyboard/mouse & continued.  Then the virtual keyboard started opening up on its own.  At one point, it appeared to open every time I hit the shift key and other times, it just randomly appeared all on its own.  Every time I managed to get a modifier key turned off using the mouse & virtual keyboard, another one would pop on.  I tried everything I could think of.  The keyboard was at 65% battery power.  I cycled bluetooth, cycled the power, etc..  No luck.  So I turned off the keyboard and tried screen sharing with the iPad again, and when it said it was authenticating, the mouse on the screen started rapidly changing between the standard cursor and the rainbow wheel.  So I tried turning the keyboard on again and as soon as I did, the cursor came back and I got VNC to connect immediately.

At one point, the keyboard started to behave, so I thought the conniption was over, and it was, for awhile.  I turned on my BT headphones and started to watch a movie.  After a little while, the audio cut out and I started going through the same process of turning on/off bluetooth, turning the headphones on/off, turning the computer on/off.  After a few minutes, I got the error I posted at the top of this post:

> “A Bluetooth audio error occurred. There was an error connecting to
>   your audio device. Make sure it is turned on and in range. The audio
>   portion of the program you were using may have to be restarted.” with
>   the only button: “Stop using headset”

Then I tried turning on the keyboard and when this was all happening with the headphones, the keyboard would not connect.  After a few minutes, the keyboard did connect, so I started googling and posting on forums and stuff and the modifier key problem came back.  It took me forever turning off the option key to get a complete sentence out.  After 10 or 15 minutes, things started working correctly again, so I’d go back to watching the movie, but after an hour or so it would all happen over again.

I can’t tell you the exact things I did each time this happened, but there were approximately 4 or 5 episodes last night, each lasting 10 or 15 minutes where bluetooth just decided to throw a fit.  I did search the console for bluetooth errors and found these, which occur at around 1am – right when I experienced the last of BT’s conniptions last night before I turned in.  The previous console entry was at around 11, so I’m pretty sure these correspond to my precise issue:

```
10/2/14 12:55:13.000 AM kernel: E:[AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController][InterruptReadHandler] immediate error (-536870175) queueing next read.
10/2/14 12:55:56.000 AM kernel: [[0x5150000] OpCode 0x0C19 from: SystemUIServer (176) status: 0x00 state: 2 timeout: 4321] Bluetooth warning: An HCI Req timeout occurred.
10/2/14 12:55:56.000 AM kernel: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x0C19] (Read Scan Enable) — Send request failed (err = 0x0010 (kBluetoothHCIErrorHostTimeout))
10/2/14 12:56:01.000 AM kernel: [[0x5150000] OpCode 0x1009 from: blued (27230) status: 0x00 state: 2 timeout: 4321] Bluetooth warning: An HCI Req timeout occurred.
10/2/14 12:56:01.000 AM kernel: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x1009] (Read Device Address) — Send request failed (err = 0x0010 (kBluetoothHCIErrorHostTimeout))
10/2/14 12:56:06.000 AM kernel: [[0x5150000] OpCode 0x0C19 from: blued (27230) status: 0x00 state: 2 timeout: 4321] Bluetooth warning: An HCI Req timeout occurred.
10/2/14 12:56:06.000 AM kernel: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x0C19] (Read Scan Enable) — Send request failed (err = 0x0010 (kBluetoothHCIErrorHostTimeout))
10/2/14 12:56:10.000 AM kernel: [[0x5150000] OpCode 0x1009 from: blued (27230) status: 0x00 state: 2 timeout: 4321] Bluetooth warning: An HCI Req timeout occurred.
10/2/14 12:56:10.000 AM kernel: [SendHCIRequestFormatted] ### ERROR: [0x1009] (Read Device Address) — Send request failed (err = 0x0010 (kBluetoothHCIErrorHostTimeout))
10/2/14 12:59:22.000 AM kernel: REQUIRE failure: mClientResponseTimedOut == false – file: /SourceCache/IOBluetoothFamily/IOBluetoothFamily-4080.4.17/Core/Family/Drivers/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriver/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDevice.cpp:701
10/2/14 12:59:22.000 AM kernel: REQUIRE failure: result == kIOReturnSuccess – file: /SourceCache/IOBluetoothFamily/IOBluetoothFamily-4080.4.17/Core/Family/Drivers/IOBluetoothSCOAudioDriver/IOBluetoothSCOAudioEngine.cpp:275
10/2/14 1:03:50.670 AM BluetoothAudioAgent: [IOBluetoothDevice instantiateChannel] BluetoothHCIAuthenticationRequested failed because not connected
10/2/14 1:03:50.000 AM kernel: E:[AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController][BulkInReadHandler] overrun error. ignoring. dataSize = 0x0
10/2/14 1:03:50.000 AM kernel: E:[AppleUSBBluetoothHCIController]WARNING !!!! [DeviceRequestCompleteHandler] error e00002eb (kIOReturnAborted)
10/2/14 1:03:54.000 AM kernel: [IOBluetoothHCIController::setConfigState] calling registerService
10/2/14 1:03:54.000 AM kernel: CSRUSBBluetoothHCIController::setupHardware super returned 0
10/2/14 1:03:59.509 AM com.apple.launchd.peruser.501: (com.apple.bluetoothAudioAgent) Throttling respawn: Will start in 1 seconds
```

The audio started working shortly there-after.  I only had 3 minutes left in my movie, so I finished that off and hit the hay.  Perhaps my BT antenna is going bad?  Maybe that combined with the system update?  I just made a genius Bar appointment so I can get to the bottom of this.  This story has also been posted on my blog:

http://alwayswithyouwhatcannotbedone.wordpress.com/2014/10/02/bluetooth-gone-haywire/

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: sorry, I could not find it in your post, did you reset the SMC ?

Comment: Sorry, it's a long post, but no, I didn't try resetting the SMC. I'll give it a shot tonight. Testing to see if anything works will be a pain. Sometimes, it'll run for over an hour without incident.